# Help understanding symbols in integral definition formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is a formula for defining a collection $K$ of analytic functions on a unit disk, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $|z|<1$. I do not understand the symbols after the integral.

$$(K \mu)(z):=\int \frac{d \mu(\zeta)}{1-\bar{\zeta} z}$$

What does zeta mean in this function? and why is there a bar on top of the zeta in the denominator?

Thanks for any help, and if any clarification is needed please ask.

Comment: $\zeta$ is the complex variable of integration, and the bar over $\zeta$ denotes complex conjugation (so if $\zeta = x + iy$, then $\bar{\zeta} = x - iy$).

Comment: @PeterOberly Thank you very much! This answer helped me grasp it which is a wonderful feeling!